# When may I apply for J1 again?

Tags: united-states, postdocs, visa

My situation is the following. Last year I got a J1 (the two year rule didn't apply) and spent 11 months in Kansas as a Research Scholar. Unfortunately, I had to terminate the contract and return to my home country, where I've spent two months. 
A week ago I was offered another postdoc position in the US. According to the information I they gave me in the US Embassy where I called to clarify the situation, I have a right to apply for another J1 this year already, just need to pay SEVIS again. But the lady from the International Program Office of the US University, where I worked last year, insists that I will be eligible for another J1 not earlier than in 2 years. 
I'm super confused. 
Could you help me with the question? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: No one here would give better information than the people responsible for that in the institutions.

Comment: It sounds as though the "lady from the International Program Office" believes that you've got a two-year return requirement on your current visa. In any case, we're in no position to answer this question.